# Texture for 3D printing

Tags: texturing, 3d-printing

[image]

How do you add a proper texture that can be 3D printed?
What I am looking at is stuff like barrels, wooden cases, that sort of stuff.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unwrap your object correctly, subdivide it enough so that it can have small details on it, then give it a *Displace* modifier with *Coordinates > UV*, open the wanted texture in the *Texture* panel, then select it in the modifier. When you're glad, apply the modifier so that it changes the topology for real.

[image]

For your current object:

- In *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to convert tris to quads
- Your object has no Uvs, in front view, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> *(Unwrap) > Cylinder Projection*. In the UV Editor stretch the UVs a bit on X, scale it if you want a repetition of your texture (if it’s repeatable), rotate it 90° if the texture is not correctly oriented
- Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (try a subdivision level of 2 for example, but if you want more details you'll need to subdivide more), duplicate your object, apply the modifier of one of the copies
- In the *Displace* modifier choose *Coordinates > UV* and lower the *Strength* value

[image]

Comment: As you see from the pics above I am trying to add wood effect to the barrel shape. Followed your instructions but finding it hard to get the planks running up and down.

Comment: You need to check your UVs in the UV Editor, please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file

Comment: for example if the planks are horizontal you need to rotate your UV faces 90° in the UV Editor...

Comment: Done as asked but struggling to get the file down to 30mb

Comment: please share the link

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=qAnQL5O6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qAnQL5O6/)

Comment: I have just imported the stl object, added wooden texture and added a displace modifier. Dont want to go further as the file gets to big. I know I should subdivide the surface but this bit add to the file size.

Comment: You need to pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), then share again, maybe use workupload.com

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/dt53ttAMRjH

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: It works perfectly thank you very much. I know its not allowed to say thanks but I feel it rude not too.

Comment: Great, you're welcome